# WebApi model with optional type

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, entity-relationship

I am writing a model in C#, which I want to have a nullable `List<>` of another model.
So I tried `public List<Location>? locations { get; set; }`.
This however errors that `List<Location>` must be non-nullable to use it as type `T` in `Nullable<T>`.

Now I also tried `public virtual List<Location>? locations { get; set; }` but it errors out the same way. Should I just use `List<Location>`, and just keep it empty when there are no locations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `List<T>` derives from `object` and so it's default type is already null

Only value types require a nullable wrapper, for example `int?` or `Nullable<DateTime>`